# How do you add a page break in a PDF with XSL-FO?

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

How do you add a page break into a document with XSL-FO? I'm using [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to create PDFs, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [FOP compliance page](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html)  says that it supports `page-break-after`, `page-break-before`, and `page-break-inside` in the later versions, plus partial support for `keep-together`, `keep-with-next`, `keep-with-previous`.

Answer (score 41):

You can also do:

```
<fo:block page-break-before="always">
  ...things you want in a new page...
</fo:block>
```

Comment: don't forget to insert a `/` when leaving the fo:block empty

Answer (score 18):

Thanks, the following worked for adding a page break after a table:

```
<fo:table break-after="page">
```

Comment: don't forget to insert a `/` when leaving the fo:block empty

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. But this is Elite Design Gallery syntax.

```
<w:p ><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>
```