PDF - add "next sheet" mark
I merge multiple documents into one PDF. So they can be printed with one click.
My users would like to print document double-sided. But they also would like to have every document on separate sheet.
I can can option in my app to add empty pages to separate documents but, maybe PDF itself offers "start new sheet of paper" command?

The short answer is "yes, PDF supports page breaks". However you haven't specified a tool/framework you use to create PDFs, so the main question "how to make a page break" is still unanswered. E.g. Apache FOP has specific tags to solve the task. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/225691/3159253
